# Jenkins pipeline does not deploy to azure

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

im trying to deploy azure web app to azure form git through jenkins pipeline

code looks like this

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'creds', url: 'https://xx.git']]]) 
        }
    }
    stage ('Development - NuGet restore') {
        steps {
            bat """
                C:\\nuget\\nuget.exe restore "%WORKSPACE%\\src\\xx.sln" 
            """
        }
    }

    stage ('Development - MSBuild') {
        steps {
            bat """ 
                "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe" msbuild "%WORKSPACE%\\src\\xx.sln" /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /p:BuildInParallel=true /m:8 /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /t:Clean,Build 
            """ 
        }
    }

    stage ('Development - Deploy') {
        steps {
            azureWebAppPublish appName: "xx",
                azureCredentialsId: 'xx',
                resourceGroup: "xx",
                filePath: 'xx'
        }
    }   
}
post {
    failure {
        xxx....;
    }
}
```

}

Output form azure deployment plugin is:

> Starting Azure Web App Deployment
>   Cloning repository https://xx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/gitfile.git
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\xx.azure-deploy # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://xx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/gitfile.git
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://xx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/gitfile.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://xx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/gitfile.git # timeout=10
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>   Seen 0 remote branches
>   c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe add -A # timeout=10
>   Deploy repository is up-to-date. Nothing to commit.
>   Done Azure Web App deployment.

Plugin is trying to fetch changes form actual azure webapp url which is obviously wrong, using correct git file name.

How is this possible? Is there any way to supply git repo url as a parameter to azure plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The comments part from [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+Function+Plugin) Azure Function Plugin link talks regarding similar issue (i.e., regarding issue of 'Deploy repository is up-to-date. Nothing to commit.') and the comment provided is to explicitly have a process to make sure the changed files are included in the 'Files' list. For more information and comparison with Azure App Service plugin, please refer it. Hope this helps!!